# How to add reference in Design time?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

It's a SDK I bought. Project-> Add reference, select the dll and reference appears succesfully.

But how do I add this to the form at design time using the designer? I saw the examples have it, but I don't know how to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bought a commercial software license and it doesn't tell you how to add its controls to the toolbox?  That's probably because it doesn't have any controls.

If it does, right-click the toolbox, Choose Items, click the Browse button.  Get support from the vendor if that doesn't help, you paid them good money for it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some control in Toolbox (View->Toolbox) and by drag and drop this controls related dll will be added to references automatically.

Comment: @John black, I live in free country and because of this I can't see your image!, would you please say what's the error message is?(I can use filter passer applications but my connection speed is in low)

Comment: @John black, I see your image, but where is a tool? did you add it from choose items in toolbox? I can't see it.